# Generate HTML/XML Markup in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, html, xml, razor, console-application

I am working a console application that generates XML/HTML output. Currently I have the code below that includes hard-coded spaghetti markup.

Is it possible to use razor or some tool to improve this and make it cleaner?

```
foreach (var file in _files)
{
    TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(file.FullName);
    string title = f.Tag.Title;

    string url = _urlPrefix + file.Name;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<item>\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<title>{0}</title>\n", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title));
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<pubDate>{0}</pubDate>\n", file.CreationTimeUtc.ToString("r"));
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<guid isPermaLink=\"false\">{0}</guid>\n", url);
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<enclosure url=\"{0}\" length=\"{1}\" type=\"audio/mpeg\" />\n", url, file.Length);
    sb.Append("\t<itunes:subtitle></itunes:subtitle>\n");
    sb.Append("\t<itunes:summary></itunes:summary>\n");
    sb.Append("</item>\n");

    items.AppendLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the System.XML classes to help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx

sample code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Foo"));
el.SetAttribute("Bar", "some & value");
el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Nested")).InnerText = "data";
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project which allows to use Razor as a general templating engine: it's called 
[razorengine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

```
 string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
 string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

I think this will helpful for you..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a StringBuilder to output XML, you can use LINQ to XML (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) or XmlWriter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) or the DOM API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t058x2df(v=vs.110).aspx).